# bash permission set to 777 but file execution still denied

Tags: bash, file, permissions, sh, execute

I wrote a bash script and am trying to execute it from sh but I am getting a "permission denied error". I set to permissions to 777 but it is still preventing me from executing the file.

```
# which sh
/bin/sh
# ls -l myscript.sh
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root  wheel  974 Nov  4 09:16 myscript.sh
# ./myscript.sh
zsh: permission denied: ./myscript.sh
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That worked. I normally run my scripts from a Ubuntu server which doesn't require the sh. Thanks.

Comment: I posted that as answer. removing from comment.

Comment: If the error message comes from `zsh`, the path to `sh` is irrelevant.  What does the first line of the script say?  What are the permissions of the `zsh` binary?

Comment: In script what is the first line you are using , Are you specifying any #! value ?

Comment: @SriharshaKalluru yes I have the shell interpreter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what could be the reason but try invoking shell explicitly passing your 
script as argument/command to the Shell like `sh myscript.sh`